# THREE.TransformControls properties and methods

Tags: javascript, three.js

Was trying to use transformControl in my program..but since little of documentation is available on controls in threejs.org I am unable to use its full potential.Wanted to know all the properties and methods provide by THREE.TransformControls.The example mentioned in the threejs.org is pretty self explanatory.The problem which I am stuck with that how can I detach object from transformControl.

```
control = new THREE.TransformControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
control.addEventListener( 'change', render );
control.attach(selected_item );
scene.add( control );
```

above statements will add control to selected_item and will add it to scene.

Now I want to remove that control from selected_item.

like 
control.remove(selected_item)

please a little help.....
Better documentation help will be appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call:

```
control.detach();
```

Line 733 of TransformControl.js

You can call this inside code to detach control object on the selected Item

Comment: thanks.....it solved my problem...but still wanted to know which code line number you have pointed...a link to those example or documentation will be appreciated more... :)

Comment: The line number is from the file TransformControl.js ( /examples/js/controls/TransformControl.js)
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/docs  honestly never tried out but things like this you can raise pull request and ask the moderator to add to provide solution toward open source. Three.js is Open source library and guys like us need to contribute to make it more rich and versatile.